# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" when trying to slice string

Tags: python

I would like to browse a list on a table which takes the coordinates of another list. But it returns an error: "'int' object is not subscriptable" even if I change the list.

```
Text = [
["B","o","n","j"],
["o","u","r"," "],
["ç","a","v","a"],
["b","i","e","n"],
]

Cle = [
['2','5','6','7'],
['9','3','1','5'],
['7','1','7','8'],
['8','4','3','0'],
]

for a in range(0,4):
    for b in range(0,4):
            Text[a][b] = ( int( ord(Text[a][b])) ^int(Cle[a][b]))

def Affichage(TextAffichage):
    print('[[', '],\n['.join([','.join(["'{:4}'".format(item) for item in  row]) for row in TextAffichage]))
    print("],\n]")

Affichage(Text)
print("*"*30)

# Substitution of the text with a data box de in decimal base
SBOX = [
['77', '23', '4', '34', '26', '34', '81', '70', '26', '86'],
['64', '96', '66', '28', '4', '2', '21', '90', '79', '83'],
['25', '13', '60', '63', '82', '36', '86', '69', '43', '17'],
['13', '80', '21', '62', '80', '92', '62', '9', '69', '40'],
['21', '76', '90', '10', '28', '32', '21', '33', '18', '56'],
['73', '50', '56', '53', '1', '7', '96', '52', '59', '98'],
['13', '80', '98', '90', '19', '30', '35', '52', '10', '55'],
['23', '85', '57', '42', '64', '50', '30', '92', '74', '86'],
['79', '4', '60', '50', '26', '76', '78', '55', '14', '32'],
['76', '43', '89', '12', '36', '49', '23', '28', '64', '37']]

x = []
y = []
Texte = []
for i in range(0,4):
    for m in range(0,4):
        x = (Text[i][m][0])
        y = (Text[i][m][1])
        Texte(i)[m] = SBOX[int(x)][int(y)]

Affichage(Text)
```

What it returns:

```
[[ '  64',' 106',' 104',' 109'],
[' 102',' 118',' 115','  37'],
[' 224','  96',' 113',' 105'],
[' 106',' 109',' 102',' 110'
],
]
******************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:Downloads\petit test sur texte.py", line 59, in <module>
    x = (Text[i][m][0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: @Waise, I imagine you want `str(Text[i][m])[0]` in place of `Text[i][m][0]` in the last loop (and similarly with `1` for the line below)

Comment: @mozway Even if I do that it desn't work, I 'll send you the first program that I made and which is working : 
Text = [
['64','76','68','67'],
['70','66','68','74'],
['64','79','69','83'],
['81','77','71','85']
]
x = []
y = []


def Affichage(TextAffichage):
    print('[[','],\n['.join([','.join(["'{:4}'".format(item) for item in row]) for row in TextAffichage]))
    print("],\n]")

Comment: @Waise try to make a minimal working example, i.e., keep only a minimal part of your code, describe what it should do, provide all inputs and the expected output

Comment: # Substitution du texte  avec une box de données en base décimale
SBOX = [...]
for i in range(0,4):
    for m in range(0,4):
        x = (Text[i][m][0])
        y = (Text[i][m][1])
        Text[i][m] = SBOX[int(x)][int(y)]
Affichage(Text)

Comment: @Waise click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69373012/edit) link to modify your question, do not paste large amount of code as comment

Comment: @mozway. It 's an algo of AES and I wanted to make it in just an one program. I have the 4 programs separately and they works but they are not efficient enough for me.

Comment: @Waise as I said, edit your question, try to make it minimal to keep only the problematic part if possible. Actually, maybe start a new question. Writing a good question is not so easy but important if you want to have answers, so take your time and keep in mind that the shortest/simplest, the more answers you'll have ;)

Comment: @mozway ok I'll try . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `Text[i][m][0]` is that `Text[i][m]` is an integer, as shown below, and as the error indicates you cannot subscript an integer. Here you can see that `Text` is only 2-dimensional, which is why `Text[i][m][0]` does not work; it is trying to index on a third dimension.

```
In [1]: Text = [
   ...: ["B","o","n","j"],
   ...: ["o","u","r"," "],
   ...: ["ç","a","v","a"],
   ...: ["b","i","e","n"],
   ...: ]
   ...:
   ...: Cle = [
   ...: ['2','5','6','7'],
   ...: ['9','3','1','5'],
   ...: ['7','1','7','8'],
   ...: ['8','4','3','0'],
   ...: ]
   ...:
   ...: for a in range(0,4):
   ...:     for b in range(0,4):
   ...:             Text[a][b] = ( int( ord(Text[a][b])) ^int(Cle[a][b]))
   ...:

In [2]: Text
Out[2]:
[[64, 106, 104, 109],
 [102, 118, 115, 37],
 [224, 96, 113, 105],
 [106, 109, 102, 110]]
```

I'm not sure why you are expecting Text to be three dimensional, though.